# bootstrap background color changes on active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Following is the code for my navbar with a navbar link named find agents:

```
 <nav id="nav" class="navbar bg-navyblue navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0" tabindex="-2">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-left inpage-links">
            <li class="find-agent-btn"><a href="#" class="fa fa-search-plus"> Find Agents <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
 </nav>
```

here is the css for it:

```
ul.inpage-links li a:hover, ul.inpage-links li a:active{
        background-color: #246B80;
        color: #fff;
        opacity: .8;
}
```

The problem is when i click the link and remove my mouse from it the default bootstrap color that is gray overrides my active class css.

[here](https://copy.com/L9lmSDIUxRhUL0DR) is an image of my work for more clarification.

Comment: Sorry, *what?* I'm reading this again and again - could you provide a jsfiddle/demo? this is just so hard to see what you're actually asking.

Comment: add: ul.inpage-links li a:focus, to your css group and you should be good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have changed classes so update css, so both type of html will work

```
ul.inpage-links li a:hover, ul.inpage-links li a:active,ul.inpage-links li a:focus{
        background-color: #246B80;
        color: #fff;
        opacity: .8;
}
ul li a.link:hover, ul li a.link:active,ul li a.link:focus,.open>a,.open>a:hover,.open>a:focus{
       background-color: #246B80 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        opacity: .8 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added property on hover and active also add on focus

```
ul.inpage-links li a:hover, ul.inpage-links li a:active,ul.inpage-links li a:focus{
        background-color: #246B80;
        color: #fff;
        opacity: .8;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me. but on another page i still have the same problem:

<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="welcome-text dropdown-toggle link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Howdy!
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#">User Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

Comment: You have changed name of class and order of classes so you have to add other css     i.e ul.inpage-links li a:hover, ul.inpage-links li a:active,ul.inpage-links li a:focus{
        background-color: #246B80;
        color: #fff;
        opacity: .8;
}
ul li a.link:hover, ul li a.link:active,ul li a.link:focus,.open>a,.open>a:hover,.open>a:focus{
       background-color: #246B80 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        opacity: .8 !important;
}